# SQL - Number of entries needed to reach given value

Tags: sql

I need to find how many records it took to reach a given value. I have a table in the below format:

```
    ID  Name        Time    Time 2
    1   Campaign 1  7       100
    2   Campaign 3  5       165
    3   Campaign 1  3       321
    4   Campaign 2  610     952
    5   Campaign 2  15      13
    6   Campaign 2  310     5
    7   Campaign 3  0       3
    8   Campaign 1  0       610
    9   Campaign 1  1       15
    10  Campaign 1  54      310
    11  Campaign 3  4       0
    12  Campaign 2  23      0
    13  Campaign 2  8       1
    14  Campaign 3  23      1
    15  Campaign 3  7       0
    16  Campaign 3  5       5
    17  Campaign 3  2       66
    18  Campaign 3  100     7
    19  Campaign 1  165     3
    20  Campaign 1  321     13
    21  Campaign 1  952     5
    22  Campaign 1  13      3
    23  Campaign 2  15      610
    24  Campaign 2  0       15
    25  Campaign 1  100     310
    26  Campaign 2  165     0
    27  Campaign 3  321     0
    28  Campaign 3  952     1
    29  Campaign 3  0       1
    30  Campaign 3  5       0
```

I'd like to find out how many entries of 'Campaign 1' there were before the total of Time1 + Time2 was equal to or greater than a given number.

As an example, the result for Campaign 1 to reach 1400 should be 5.

Apologies if I haven't explained this clearly enough - the concept is still a little muddy at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: So you want the number of entries, not the entries themselves, right?

Comment: What is the version of the SQL Server?

Comment: So you want to find out how much effort it took to achieve a target in, say marketing campagin ? Eg. In (sales) campaign 1, we had to make 700 calls to reach a Sales of $1000 ?

Comment: Correct, Borat Sagdiyev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, you can get the row using:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(time1 + time2) over (partition by name order by id) as cumsum
      from table t
     ) t
where cumsum >= @VALUE and (cumsum - (time1 + time2)) < @VALUE;
```

You can get the count using:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select t.*, sum(time1 + time2) over (partition by name order by id) as cumsum
      from table t
     ) t
where (cumsum - (time1 + time2)) < @VALUE
group by name;
```

If you are not using SQL Server 2012, you can do the cumulative sum with a correlated subquery:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(time1 + time2) 
              from table t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.id <= t.id
             ) as cumsum
      from table t
     ) t
where (cumsum - (time1 + time2)) < @VALUE
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE computing a running total should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT id,
         name,
         SUM([time]+[time 2])
    OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
          AS RunningTotal
  FROM Table1
  WHERE name = 'Campaign 1'
)
SELECT count(*)+1 AS [Count]
FROM CTE
WHERE RunningTotal < 1400
```

Note that I added 1 to the count as the query counts the number of rows needed to reach up to, but not including, 1400. Logic dictates that the next row will push the value above 1400.

Comment: This is great, however, how can I do it over a specific date range? I have a date/time column and would like the number of entries needed to reach '1400' for each day

Comment: @user3482447 If you want to use a specific range, just add it to the `where`clause in the query for the CTE.

Comment: I know I can specify a date range that way, but I want to include the date in the output, so the output would be: 01/01/2014 - 1000, 01/02/2014 - 1500 etc..

Comment: @user3482447 Is there a date column in the data set? I don't see any - where do you get the date?

Comment: Yes, there is a column but it wasn't included in the original post. Its a column called DateTime

Comment: @user3482447 I think you should post a new question based on this and the added requirements so that it might get attention from more people. I'm not sure how to solve it and don't have time to dig deeper into in at the moment.